# How (or how quickly) does block information become available to nodes?

Tags: substrate-node-template

We have an indexing process that subscribes to finalized blocks through the Websocket interface and triggers a lightweight indexing job for that block.

The indexing job then fetches, in sequence and over HTTP/RPC, block information through `chain_getBlock` and events for that block by calling `state_getStorage` with the block's hash.

We're seeing an issue in this process where `chain_getBlock` succeeds but `state_getStorage` fails with `-32000 UnknownBlock: Header was not found in the database`. The block can be found in the Polkadot UI.

How is this possible? Strangely enough, while the indexing process has not changed in over a month, we're seeing this repeatedly as of two days ago, with no other obviously-related changes.

The only thing I can presume is that given the non-sticky nature of HTTP, the first and the second call can be routed to different nodes and the second node's storage isn't up to sync. Can there be any truth to that?

Comment: You run an indexing service against some public RPC server?

Comment: @bkchr it's a private deployment of substrate nodes. But why would that matter either way?